# How do I use a string from my Main method in another function?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, reference

In my static void Main method I have a string variable 'Name'. I want to use Name in a sub method.

```
//Main method holds Name
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
 WriteLine("Please Enter Name);
 string Name = ReadLine();
}


static void subMethod() 
{
// subMethod wants to use Name
                foreach (char i in Name)
                {
                    Write("~");
                }
}
```

I thought that since both of these functions were in the same class that the sub function would automatically know what Name is since it's used in the Main method.

I've looked online and have tried different ways to reference the variable in
The closest I've gotten to be able to do this (or at least what has given me the least amount of error messages) is write this in my sub method:

```
//Main method holds Name
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
 WriteLine("Please Enter Name);
 string Name = ReadLine();
}


static void subMethod() 
{
//This is my attempt at referencing "Name" from Main        
string Name = Main(Name);

// subMethod wants to use Name
                foreach (char i in Name)
                {
                    Write("~");
                }
}
```

When I have this in my sub method I get these errors:

CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'string[]'
CS0165 Use of unassigned local variable 'Name'

When I look up the error codes, it takes me to Microsoft, but everything they say about it is just a bunch of jargon that I can't understand (I'm very new to c#). It'd help a lot if anyone explained their solution as if you're talking to a 5 year old.

Comment: In the first code, `Name` is local variable that does not exist outside of `Main`. You can pass it to `subMethod` as an argument.

Comment: Arguments, fields, objects, … This should be explained in the most basic of tutorials (and is identical for almost every main stream programming language)

Comment: In the code shown, it doesn't appear that you ever call `subMethod`, and you also have `Main` defined to return `void`, so it doesn't make sense to try to assign it's return value to anything like you do here: `string Name = Main(Name)`

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few mistakes in your code:

```
 WriteLine("Please Enter Name);
```

You cannot just call WriteLine, you wanna tell the Console to WriteLine (or ReadLine). You are also missing quotation marks, it should be:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Name");
```

After fixing this, you can pass an argument to method like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Name");
      
         string Name = Console.ReadLine();
         subMethod(Name);
    }

    static void subMethod(string name)
    {
         string Name = name;

         //subMethod wants to use Name
         foreach (char i in Name)
         {
             Console.Write("~");
         }

    }
```

For learning C# I would recommend watching tutorials on youtube, or reading them on some websites (f.e. [here](https://www.w3schools.com/CS/index.php)), microsoft documentation is good, but it might be a little bit too complicated for beginners.

Comment: If he has `using System.Console` in the namespace he can certainly just call `WriteLine`

Comment: Passing arguments is one way to do it. Another way is to have a class field or property that stores the value.

Comment: Where is `someArgument` defined? Why not use the `name` argument directly?

Comment: someArgument is not really defined anywhere, I would say it is "substituted". When defining a method you define, how it is called. For example here you are saying: I want to have a method called subMethod, and when someone calls it, he has to give it some string ( name), which you are going to call whatever you want (someArgument). So when you call subMethod(name), the someArgument gets "replaced" by name. The reason you cannot use the name directly is, that you can use only variables from the same method (one method does not see in the others).

Comment: You could also solve this by declaring the variable as a class field, but you will get to that later (it is not always the right solution, especially for such small things, and i guess in this case it would have to be static). Btw. forgot that you can use namespaces with console, thx :-D

Comment: You code won't compile as it's written. `someArgument` needs to be defined. It seems like you should be using the `name` argument here, but it's really not clear why you would declare a new `Name` variable when you have the `name` argument available for use within the method. You could just remove the line that assigns a new variable and replace `Name` with `name`  in the `foreach` loop.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I edited the answer and forgot this line. Thank you.

Comment: Sure, no problem. BTW, what is the point of `string Name = name`? Why not just use `name` in the loop condition?

Comment: I just thought it is easier to see, how the value is passed.